# Mac Numbers - How do I add up cells containing data (text) per column

Tags: mac, numbers

In my Mac Numbers Spreadsheet, I have got a column containing a product title. I would like to add up the cells containing a title at the bottom on my spreadsheet. What formula do I use for that?
Please note: Some of the cells are empty.

Comment: He wants to count. Summing the text would be meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

This is a job for COUNTIF(). The syntax is not complicated, but it is briefly described here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5954557?tstart=0 There are also a number of questions showing how to use it in this SE if you search 'COUNTIF'.

Answer (score 1):

The function you need is CountIf, which takes two parameters: a range of cells and a test condition. Suppose you have a chart of customers and product purchases, and you want to tally what each customer purchased each quarter:
[image: **spreadsheet sample data**]

Cell B11 contains the formula `COUNTIF(B2:B10,"=Product A")` and 
Cell C12 contains the formula `COUNTIF(C2:C10,"=Product B")`, etc.

The first parameter is the range of cells you are counting in. The test condition must be enclosed in quotes, and usually you're going to want to specify a comparison operator. For more complex queries like using other cells, etc., you'll want to search Google or Ask Different.